# Dynamically rendering Polymer Web component layouts - What are recommended approaches?

Tags: templates, layout, polymer

Dynamically rendering Polymer Web component layouts - What are recommended approaches?

Is there any sort of "Polymeric" way to do layout template rendering.  I have a set of reusable Polymer tags that can be configured using attributes.  I want to do higher level dynamic rendering of these tags based on data that gets fed into the main page. (e.g. for example loop over the Polymer tags and render N-number of templates based on an array customers, orders, etc.)

Right now I'm doing this using John Resig's micro-templating and I suppose any template engine would work (browser or server-side).  Just wondering if there's a Polymer-specific way to render the naked Web components based on dynamic data in the DOM without going back to my old approaches (e.g. using another template engine to render polymer tags in the DOM).

What are the recommended approaches to handle data-driven layout of Polymer tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `is="auto-binding"` template attribute.

`<template is="auto-binding"></template>`

http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#bindingoutside

This gives you Polymer data binding without a full-blown custom element. The other option is to make another Polymer "customers" or "page" element that represents the collection you're rendering.

Comment: Perfect. This is just what I was looking for.  Creating a polymer component for each page layout seemed redundant and possibly limiting.  Also, haded the idea pulling in extra libs for the highest level layout template rendering.  I was kind of hoping Polymer had this baked in somewhere.  Looks they did.  Awesomeness!